# Who is Lola's mom in the New World?

Tags: one-piece

During the Thriller Bark Arc Lola mentioned to Luffy that her mother is in the New World and indicates that she is a extremely powerful pirate. She even left Luffy a vivre card that if ever he runs into any trouble he could ask her 'Mama' to help him out.

Who could possibly be this extremely powerful pirate Lola's mother?

Comment: She might refer to Big Mama when saying `It's Mama's vivre card` back in thriller bark arc. Tamago and Pekoms refer Big Mom as `Mama` too. Lola might not refer Mama as her real Mom imo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**We know nothing about that as of this writing, but there has been a widely circulating theory for a while now that Big Mom is Lola's mom.** You can read about it on various sites. I'll list a few points made in support of the argument on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/20d6jr/expanding_on_the_lolas_mom_theory_tinfoil/)

> Firstly, for those that don't already know the theory, it is that Big Mom is Lola's mother. Back on Thriller Bark Lola gave Nami a vivre card with Lola's signature, saying her mother is a pirate in the New World. People believe this mother is Big Mom because:
>
> - Big Mom's name is Big Mom, ie, she is known as a mother.
> - **Big Mom is in the New World**
> - **Big Mom's jolly roger has big red lips and the same colour hair as Lola**
> - **Nami who has Lola's vivre card just happens to be on the ship that is being attacked by the Big Mom pirates**
> - Nami is likely to eventually pull out the vivre card that Law gave her and accidentally pull out Lola's card instead.

Here is the similarity between Big Mom's jolly roger and Lola's face:
[image]

Another few points made in the [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Lola's_mother_is_definitely....) are:

> - **Big Mom is in the New World and thats where Lola was born**
> - **Lola's crew also said that her mother was an extremely powerful pirate which is another connection between the two**
> - **Luffy will definitely meet Lola's mother on account that the crew was given her vivre card and it only makes sense that Luffy meets all members of the Yonkou**

Lola's crew stating that Lola's mom is an amazing pirate:

[image]

---

**Another popular theory recently is that her mom is [Miss Bakkin](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bakkin)**

The arguments in support of these [here](http://www.onepiecelove.com/lolas-mother-is-miss-bakkin-theory/) are:

> - **Miss Bakkin is the first pirate woman to be introduce for a while and she is a mother which is really rare in One Piece, since all mothers are dead.**
> - **Miss Bakkin and Lola have the same hair style, Weeble has the same type of hair braids, Lola’s mouth looks similar to that of Miss Bakkin.**
> - **Bakkin also claims to be Whitebeard’s lover, while Lola has been desperate to find a lover herself. Is she possibly trying to imitate her mother?**
> - **The other connection to Lola is Thriller Bark itself. Lola’s reason for being in Thriller Bark could have been a search for Hogback. Maybe Weeble needed a doctor and they thought Dr. Hogback could help them. This would explain the stitches on his face, around his neck, and his arm.**

Similarity between Lola, Miss Bakkin and Weeble:

[image]

---

Obviously, t**his is all speculation at this poin**t and we won't know who her real mom is unless revealed by Oda himself. Although, based on these theories, it's likely that it's either going to be Big Mom or Miss Bakkin.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great answer. Anyway my bet is 'Big Mam' as many others do. :)

Comment: @bot, as far as I know, yes. Accepting an answer only has to do with the questioner. If you feel satisfied with this answer, then yes. Also, no problem :). Even I think it's Big Mom.

Comment: You can read about accepting an answer [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Well.. I asked the question before the truth was revealed so I think no one here will complain if I accepts an answer based from speculation. Anyway if the truth will be revealed sooner I will update the question with answer to make it trustworthy question and answer.

Comment: @bot, you should rather update my answer. Answering the question in the question itself is not encouraged. You can choose to post another answer as well. Most likely, I'll update this answer myself when the name of her mom is revealed.

Comment: Ok then. Maybe you could just put UPDATE below your answer right now if the truth will be revealed to distinguish your old answer from the new.

Comment: Its been Revealed.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the update. I'll update the answer in the next 2 days

Answer (score 0):

It's Big Mom, confirmed in chapter 835

Answer (score -1):

Manga chapter 835 page 20

Chapter 835 shows both parents

[image]

Comment: Please don't link to scanlation sites, and please don't leave answers with just a link in them and no explanation.

Comment: As @Torisuda stated, please explain the above picture with regard to the asked question, rather than just posting a _seemingly_ unrelated picture.